# Powershell 2.0: how to -match or -like a string in hash table keys

Tags: string, key, match, hashtable, powershell-2.0

For Powershell 2.0:

I have a hash table with several strings as keys. Unlike `@{}.containskey`, is it possible to find a key (e.g., `"examplekey"`) using wildcards (e.g., `"*xampl*"`)?

I managed to accomplish what I wanted making a list of the keys and using Where-Object as a filter. But is there a simpler way to do it? I think this method is specially bad when I'm adding new keys, because I need to recreate the list everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.Keys` property and `-like` or `-notlike` operators that return an array of keys (or a single key):

```ps
if ($hash.keys -notlike '*xampl*') {
    $hash.example = 1
}
```

Store the keys in an array for multiple checks:

```ps
$keys = $hash.keys
if ($keys -notlike '*xampl*') {
    $hash.example = 1
}
if ($keys -notlike '*foo*') {
    $hash.example = 1
}
```

Chain the comparisons:

```ps
if ($hash.keys -notlike '*xampl*' -notlike '*123*') {
    $hash.example = 1
}
```

Or use regexp in case there are lots of keys and you want to perform lots of checks:

```ps
if ($hash.keys -join "`n" -match '(?mi)xampl|foo|bar|^herp\d+|\wDerp$|^and$|\bso\b|on') {
   echo 'Already present'
} else {
   $hash.foo123 = 'bar'
   # ......
}
```

`(?mi)` means **m**ultiline case-**i**nsensitive mode: each key is tested individually.